# uploading (multiple)image with data in same form

Tags: php

i'm trying to make this form with pdo where you can insert a a data and multiple image in the same form and currently, this is my problem:
html:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" name="postHome" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])?>" method="post">

            <table border="0" style="width: auto; line-height: 300%">
                <p>
                <tr>
                    <td><u>Advertisement Details:</u></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Title:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="home_adTitle" width="500px" placeholder="Title" class="text-input" required="required"></td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                    <td valign="top">Description:</td>
                    <td><textarea rows="5" cols="50" input type="text" name="home_description" width="400px"></textarea></td>
                </tr>
               </p>

               <p>
               <br>
               <tr>
                   <td><u>Homestay Details:</u></td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                   <td>Homestay Name:</td>
                   <td><input type="text" name="home_name" width="500px" placeholder="Homestay name" class="text-input"></td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                    <td>Category: </td>
                    <td><select name="home_category">
                        <option value>Choose category</option>
                        <option value="1">Room</option>
                        <option value="2">Apartment</option>
                        <option value="3">Terrace</option>
                        <option value="4">Bungalow</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Area: </td>
                    <td><select name="Area" required="required">
                        <option value>Choose area</option>
                        <option value="1">Area 1</option>
                        <option value="2">Area 2</option>
                        <option value="3">Area 3</option>
                        <option value="4">Area 4</option>
                        <option value="5">Area 5</option>
                        <option value="6">Area 6</option>
                        <option value="7">Area 7</option>
                        <option value="8">Area 8</option>
                        <option value="9">Area 9</option>
                        <option value="10">Area 10</option>
                        <option value="11">Area 11</option>
                        <option value="12">Area 12</option>
                        <option value="13">Area 13</option>
                        <option value="14">Area 14</option>
                        <option value="15">Area 15</option>
                        <option value="16">Area 16</option>
                        <option value="17">Area 17</option>
                        <option value="18">Area 18</option>
                        <option value="19">Area 19</option>
                        <option value="20">Area 20</option>
                        <option value="21">Area 21</option>
                        <option value="22">Area 22</option>
                        <option value="23">Area 23</option>
                        <option value="24">Area 24</option>
                        <option value="25">Area 25</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top">Address:</td>
                        <td><textarea rows="1" cols="50" input type="text" name="home_add" width="400px" class="add" required="required"></textarea></td>
                        <tr>
                        <td valign="top"></td>
                        <td><textarea rows="1" cols="50" input type="text" name="home_add2" width="400px" class="add" required="required"></textarea></td>
                        <tr>
                        <td valign="top"></td>
                        <td><textarea rows="1"  input type="text" name="home_add3" class="add" ></textarea></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                       <td>No. of room(s):</td> 
                       <td><input type="number" name="no_room" width="60px" class="text2" required="required"> </td>

                   </tr>
                    <tr>
                       <td>Air-condition:</td>

                       <td><input type="radio" name="ac_avail" value="1">Yes &nbsp; &nbsp; <input type="radio" name="ac_avail" value="0">No</td>

                   </tr>
                </p>

                <p>
                <tr>
                       <td>Contact No:</td>
                       <td><input type="text" name="home_tel" width="300px" placeholder="Contact No." class="phone" required="required"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr colspan=2>
                    <td>Rental: </td>
                    <td><b>RM &nbsp; </b><input type="number" name="price" width="50px" placeholder="00.00"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Deposit: </td>
                    <td><b>RM &nbsp; </b><input type="number" name="home_deposit" width="50px" placeholder="00.00" class="text"></td>
                </tr>
                </p>

                <p>
                <tr>
                    <td align="left">Images:</td>
                    <td><input type="file" id="file" name="file[]" width="200px" height="200px" multiple="multiple"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>

            <br>
            <input type="submit" name="postHome" value="POST" class="button large">
</p>
</form>
```

when i try to upload it without the php of the image, its success but when i insert the image php it became -> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

php:

```
if(isset($_POST['postHome'])) //postHome name is taken from the name place for the submit button
    {       
        $userid=$_SESSION['oid'];
        $h_id=null;
        $h_title= $_POST['home_adTitle'];
        $h_name= $_POST['home_name'];
        $h_category= $_POST['home_category'];
        $h_add1= $_POST['home_add'];
        $h_add2= $_POST['home_add2'];
        $h_add3= $_POST['home_add3'];
        $h_area= $_POST['area'];
        $h_desc= $_POST['home_description'];
        $h_price= $_POST['price'];
        $h_deposit= $_POST['home_deposit'];
        $h_tel = $_POST['home_tel'];
        $h_ac = $_POST['ac_avail'];
        $h_room = $_POST['no_room'];

        $h_status = 1; //h_status: 1-available 0-unavailable
        $query = $conn->prepare("SELECT home_name FROM homestay WHERE home_name=:home_name");   //2: select table from db. if use //3: prepare statement
        $query->bindParam(':home_name', $h_name);
        $query->execute();


        if($query->rowCount() > 0)
        {

            echo 'existed already';
        } 
        else 
        {
            // Prepaire SQL Statement
            $query = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO homestay (home_id, home_name, ac_avail, no_room, price, home_category, home_tel, home_deposit, home_add, home_add2, home_add3, area, home_description, home_adTitle, status, o_id)             
            VALUES(null, :home_name, :ac_avail, :no_room, :price, :home_category, :home_tel, :home_deposit, :home_add, :home_add2, :home_add3, :area, :home_description, :home_adTitle, :status, :o_id)");


            $query->bindParam(':home_name', $h_name);
            $query->bindParam(':ac_avail', $h_ac);
            $query->bindParam(':no_room', $h_room);
            $query->bindParam(':price', $h_price);
            $query->bindParam(':home_category', $h_category);
            $query->bindParam(':home_tel', $h_tel);
            $query->bindParam(':home_deposit', $h_deposit);
            $query->bindParam(':home_add', $h_add1);
            $query->bindParam(':home_add2', $h_add2);
            $query->bindParam(':home_add3', $h_add3);
            $query->bindParam(':area', $h_area);
            $query->bindParam(':home_description', $h_desc);
            $query->bindParam(':home_adTitle', $h_title);
            $query->bindParam(':status', $h_status);
            $query->bindParam(':o_id', $userid);


            //IMAGE 
            function microtime_name()
            {
                list($usec, $sec) = explode(" ", microtime());
                return ($usec + $sec)*10000;            
            }
            $j=0;
            foreach($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] as $key=>$name_tmp)
            {
                $target_path='home_image/';
                // Loop to get individual element from the array
                $validextensions = array("jpeg", "jpg", "png");      // Extensions which are allowed.
                $ext = explode('.', basename($_FILES['file']['name'][$key]));   // Explode file name from dot(.)
                $file_extension = end($ext); // Store extensions in the variable.
                $namePic=microtime_name(); 
                $target_path = $target_path . $namePic . "." . $ext[count($ext) - 1];     // Set the target path with a new name of image.
                if (in_array($file_extension, $validextensions))//in_array check if value(in this case: $file_extension) exist in array or not(in this case: $validextensions)
                {
                    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$key], $target_path))
                    {
                        // If file moved to uploads folder.
                        //echo $j. ').<span id="noerror">Image uploaded successfully!.</span><br/><br/>';
                        $image_name=$target_path;
                        $stmt=$conn->prepare("INSERT INTO h_image(image_id, image_name, home_id) VALUES (null, :image_name, null)");
                        $stmt->bindParam(':pic_path', $image_name);
                        echo $image_name.': <br>';
                        $stmt->execute();
                        //if($stmt)
                            echo 'success!<br>';

                    } 
                    else 
                    {     //  If File Was Not Moved.
                        echo $j. ').<span id="error">please try again!.</span><br/><br/>';
                    }
                } 

                else 
                {     //   If File Size And File Type Was Incorrect.
                    echo $j. ').<span id="error">***Invalid file Size or Type***</span><br/><br/>';
                }
            }

            if($query->execute())
            {
                $h_id=$conn->lastInsertId('home_id');
            echo '<br>home id is:'.$h_id;
                $test="select home_id from homestay";
                $test=$conn->prepare($test);
                $test->execute();
                if($test->rowCount() > 0)   
                {
                $r = $test->fetch(PDO::FETCH_LAZY);

                }

            }
        }   
    }
```

Comment: foreach($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']  as $key=>$name_tmp) here should be your problem. $_FILES['file'] is an index array and it needs one more foreach before you can use its ['tmp_name'] index

Comment: i don't think that's the problem. i tried to swith the lines postition and manage to get it right. but the main point is to put if(isset($_POST['postHome'])) after //IMAGE. it means i put if(isset($_POST['postHome'])) two times. once at the data and another for the image upload